# Get selectedIndex from list menu and put it in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, drop-down-menu

Here I have a code `function findPlaces` that search for places objects in box etc.

```
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: ["museum"]
   };
```

and this work fine but now...

Now I want to change this type with value from list/menu so I do that:

```
//JS CODE
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex
   };
```

and HTML code:

```
<label for="select"></label>
        <select name="select" id="select">
          <option>restaurant</option>
          <option>bar</option>
          <option>museum</option>
          <option>gas_station</option>
        </select>
```

and this code won't to get value from list/menu and run function with new value

How I can solve that?

Comment: Check `types`' value, it should be an int(the index of the selected option, as the name states). To get the selected option's value you have to do this: `document.getElementById("select")[document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex].value`

Comment: look here: http://jsbin.com/UNuRexA/5 , dont work again

Comment: or this: http://jsbin.com/UNuRexA/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery Code,once you select element , you will send the index to findPlaces , and this will alert it :

```
$("#select").change(function(){

        var values= $('#select option').map(function(){
                        return this.value;
                    }).get();
        var index=jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), values);
      
        findPlaces(boxes, index);//send index to your function

    });
```

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vQVHM/)

Comment: ok, but how to adapt in my code here: http://jsbin.com/UNuRexA/6/edit and http://jsbin.com/UNuRexA/6

Comment: I try this: $("#select").change(function(){

        var values= $('#select option').map(function(){
                        return this.value;
                    }).get();
        var index=jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), values);
      
        findPlaces(index);//send index to your function

    });
 

  function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
            types: ["index"]
   }; bt dont work

Comment: I don't know what is boxes , but you should define it and call it , replace findPlaces(index); by findPlaces(boxes, index);

Comment: I ONLY NEED TO CHANGE TYPE AND AFTER THAT UPDATE THE FUNCTION findPlaces, thats all! – Marco Jordan just now edit

Comment: no no no, searchIndex is something different and I cant chage it with index

Comment: so here is just type is important nothing else

Comment: this is here important:    var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
            types: ["restaurant"]
   }; ... so var request is important

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the select value like this:

```
var boxes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function findPlaces(boxes, searchIndex) {
   var select = document.getElementById("select")
   return {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
   };
}

document.getElementById("select").onclick = function() {

    var r = findPlaces(boxes, 2);
    alert(r.types);
};
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zaCZw/

Comment: yes but boxes I dont need to change, I dont need this array boxes

Comment: "boxes" array is there just as an example.

Comment: again dont work: try http://jsbin.com/UNuRexA/6/edit or demo: http://jsbin.com/UNuRexA/6

Comment: When should `findPlaces` be called? Also, you don't need to copy the part with `onclick`, wich it's only purpose is to show the value with an alert.

Comment: I also now try this: $("#select").change(function(){

        var values= $('#select option').map(function(){
                        return this.value;
                    }).get();
        var index=jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), values);
      
        findPlaces(index);//send index to your function

    });
 

  function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
            types: ["index"]
   }; but dont work

Comment: I ONLY NEED TO CHANGE TYPE AND AFTER THAT UPDATE THE FUNCTION findPlaces, thats all!

Comment: here just 'type' is important

Comment: var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
            types: ["restaurant"]
   }; - this is important not function

Comment: The job of retreiving the value, wich is what you asked for, is working. You have some other problem. I can't work over your example, because it's a mess. I'm sorry to say that. You should first understand the examples in the answers we gave you, and then adapt it to your code, and not try to keep doing things without having a clue of what's happenning. I don't mean to be rude.